# Flash CS5: AS3 - remove ending of swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I made a video in flash which somehow got corrupted, so the fla is no longer usable.  Instead of remaking the video, I would like to just snip off the end of the .swf that I published and then probably just play a second .swf immediately after to end it (with replay buttons and a link to a particular website)

My question is: Is it possible for me to cut the .swf by about 3 seconds at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a frame-based animation or swf, when you load the swf you can get the total number of frames using MovieClip(mySwf).currentScene.numFrames. So the way you would shave off 3 seconds would be to work out how many frames 3 seconds would be based on the current framerate, then inside an ENTER_FRAME callback check the currentFrame and act when you detect it is equal to (totalFrames less 3 seconds worth of frames). The code looks like:

* **Note: Code edited, see comments** *

```
var mySwf:MovieClip;
var reducedTotalFrames:int;

var clipLoader:Loader = new Loader();
clipLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
clipLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.mysite.com/mySwf.swf"));

function loadComplete(e:Event):void
{
     mySwf = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content as MovieClip;

     var totalFrameCount:int = mySwf.currentScene.numFrames;

     var secondsToSubtract:int = 3;

     var threeSecondFrameCount:int = (stage.frameRate * secondsToSubtract);

     reducedTotalFrames = totalFrameCount - threeSecondFrameCount;

     stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onRender);

     stage.addChild(mySwf);

     mySwf.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

function onRender(e:Event):void
{
     if(mySwf != null && mySwf.currentFrame >= reducedTotalFrames){
          //This is the end of the SWF with 3 seconds trimmed off. Here we can stop play
          stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onRender);
          mySwf.stop();
          doSomethingElse();
     }
}
```

Code is off the top of my head but at the very least, if it doesn't already work as-is, you should have a solid enough understanding of the concept to make it work or implement it as you see fit.

Comment: So basically I would be making another movie clip that plays my swf, but cuts it out when I want it to?

I'm not exactly a pro at flash nor AS3, so please excuse my ignorance

Comment: No problem at all we all start somewhere. Anyway yes that is pretty much the idea use another SWF to load in the old one, use the Loader object to load the SWF and do what I did above. I'll edit the answer to include this code.

Comment: Answer has been updated. You'll probably have to manually do the imports (for things like LoaderInfo etc) but that code should be functional. Also check out this site, it's packed with free video tutorials + project files for flash: http://gotoandlearn.com/.

Comment: No problem at all. Note though that I JUST edited the code again, lol I forgot the add the loaded SWF to the stage, otherwise you'd never see it. :)

Comment: I added the code with the url of the swf file that I have and it is giving me this error:  Frame 1, Line 28 1120: Access of undefined property reducedTotalFrames.

Comment: it works now, but for some reason the audio with the swf is playing two different times, like a fraction of a second apart from eachother.  and it fails to cut out at any time in the movie as well.  I changed the secondsToSubtract to 300 and it still didn't do anything

Comment: You probably have an audio stream attached to the timeline, which is going to be an issue. Try removing the "mySwf.gotoAndPlay(1);" bit of code.

Comment: That fixed the audio problem, but the movie still wont cut out. I changed the "3" to 30, 300, 3000 and still nothing :[

Comment: is there any way that I could set it so that the swf could play for X seconds? Instead of subtracting seconds from it.

Comment: Well that is essentially what you're doing. There must be some disconnect here as this code should work.